# I cant install Albert Launcher on Linux Mint 20 Ulyana (Depends: libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.4~rc1) )

Tags: linux-mint

**Steps i did**:

```
curl https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:manuelschneid3r/public_key | sudo apt-key add -
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_20.04/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:manuelschneid3r.list
sudo wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_20.04/Release.key -O "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:manuelschneid3r.asc"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install albert
```

**Error on command line when `sudo apt install albert`:**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
albert : Depends: libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.4~rc1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have little experience installing Mint programs, any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you did everything right. According to the release file, you need libpython3.8, not 3.6 (the default with Ubuntu 18.x). I would either contact the developer, or download the packages from here and install them manually: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/

Comment: It isn't a good idea to install packages from another distro onto your system. Your best option is to compile the software from source.

Comment: How do I do that? can you suggest me some way? Thank you @NasirRiley

Comment: This works! Thank you @ajgringo619